# Using select2 with json data that doesn't have a field called "text" while avoiding copying the items and loosing standard behaviors

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm using `select2` and I want to set a custom field for the `text` property of the rendered items without

- replacing standard behavior (marking and such)
- pushin all my array into a new one with the text field on it

  - ps: i just want to a render many select2 items that doesn't have a `text` field

Basically if you see [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ineXuNAx/2/edit) you will see something like this

```js
$("#e10_3").select2({
    data:{ results: data, text: function(item) { return item.tag; } },
    formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format
});
```

But if I delete the custom formatSelection and formatResult parameters of select2 I loose my hability to use a different field for `text`.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2463

Comment: I **do** have a workaround, it is ugly :$, but I can share it with you if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous answer this solution DOES create a new array, but it seems to be a better approach considering readability. Before passing data you should modify it. You can see this in [official docs](https://select2.github.io/options.html#my-objects-use-a-property-other-than-text-for-the-text-that-nee)

```
var data = $.map(yourArrayData, function (obj) { 
   obj.text = obj.text || obj.name; // desired field
   return obj;
});
```

The only other option is to prepare data with `text` property matched to desired property from the very beginning.

#### UPDATE (added an example)

```
$('your-select2-el').select2
  data: $.map(yourArrayData, (obj) ->
    obj.text = obj.your_custom_field_name # obj.title or obj.name etc.
    obj
  )
```

See docs in the link I provided before and [this one](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id)

Comment: I dont really follow. Can you provide more code or an example?

Comment: @genuinefafa I updated my answer with an example and one more link to official docs

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this approach

```
$("#e10_3").select2({
    data:{
        results:  function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.tag,
                        id: item.id
                        ...
                    }
                })
            };
        }
    },
    formatSelection: format,
    formatResult: format
});
```

Comment: Will this retain standard behavior of the select2? @tolo-palmer

Comment: Still working for me, at aware of newer versions. Can you post your error?

Comment: the problem is that your _solution_ is creating a new array, i don't really wanna do that (i'm using a MVC JS framework under the hood) :(

Comment: Either you create a new object or your object must be compatible with select2 (id and text property must be available)